# Asp.net LoadViewState and ItemCommand Never Firing

Tags: asp.net

I converted one of my apps a little while ago from .NET 2 to .NET 4 and I've just noticed a problem on a couple of pages.  For some reason the `LoadViewState` and Itemcommand (repeater) are never fired so the page is not working.  This was working before and now it's not!  I've tried all sorts but can never get any of of the events to trigger/debug.
`Viewstate` is enabled at the page level and this is running in a usercontrol.

Just wondering if anyone had some ideas I could try as I'm really stuck with this now.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Besides EnableViewState there is ViewStateMode. Read http://www.mostlylucid.co.uk/archive/2009/01/28/1312.aspx and see if it helps.

Comment: Didn't know about that one so set it to enabled but still nothing fires, it seems to like executing SaveViewState twice for a request but still no ItemCommand :-(

Comment: Does any other Repeater event fire? Like any of the databinding events.

Comment: The ItemBound event fires, it's strange a few pages have all stopped since I upgraded.

Comment: I found the problem, for some reason I need to put EnableEventValidation="false" into a lot of my pages to make them work correctly.  Another half day gone, can't wait to replace this app with MVC!